# How to Execute Stored Procedure SQL Server?

Tags: laravel, stored-procedures, controller

How to execute the stored procedure and use the STORE method on my Laravel resource controller? I'm new to laravel. Thanks!

For example:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $validatedData = $request->validate([
     'sample_data1' =>'',
     'sample_data2' =>''
    ]);
    dump($request->all());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call stored procedure like this in laravel but you have already created procedure in you database server.

```
$data = \DB::select('CALL procedure_name('.$para1.',"'.$para2.'")');
```